# Deploy Container in K8s in case of only config Map change argocd

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, configmap, argocd, gitops

I want to redeploy an application in k8s using GitOps(ArgoCD) in case of an only config Map change, how ArgoCD will understand to restart the container as we all know without restarting the container new config map is not going to take effect.

Scenario - If one container is running from ArgoCD and I have to modify configmap yaml file in GitHub and ArgoCD will automatically understand and sync the updated values but container will not restart as we are not modifying in Deployment Yaml Files, so how config map will take effect in the container

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround for the above question, We can include a parameter(Jenkins Build Number) as env variable in the Deployment config and it will be updated on every build from CI Pipeline, so in case of only config Change in Git repo, deployment will also be rolled out because Build number Parameter will change after running the Pipelines and as we all know ArgoCD will automatically be triggered once any change is done in Git repo connected to ArgoCD

Answer (score 0):

ArgoCD itself doesn't handle this, however other tools can. With Helm this is generally handled inside the chart by hashing the config content into an annotation in the pod template. Kustomize offers the configmap and secret generators which put a hash in the object name and rewrite the pod template to include it. There's also operator solutions like [Reloader](https://github.com/stakater/Reloader) which does a similar trick to Helm but via an operator.